# Корона и Якорь на JS

Tags: javascript

выполнял задание по JS, там надо было сделать игру Корона и Якорь. И вроде все довольно ясно, и код сравнил с кодом учебника, но не понимаю почему в консоль не выводятся числа.

```js
//возвращает случайное целое число в диапазоне [m, n] (включительно)
function rand(m, n) {
  return m + Math.floor((n - m + 1) * Math.random());
}

//случайно возвращает строку, представляющую одну из шести граней
//Короны и Якоря
function randFace() {
  return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"][rand(0, 5)];
}

let funds = 50; //Начальное условие
let round = 0;

while (funds > 1 && funds < 100) {
  round++;
  console.log("round ${round}:");
  console.log("\tstarting funds: ${funds}p");

  //Размещение ставок
  let bets = { crown: 0, anchor: 0, heart: 0, spade: 0, club: 0, diamond: 0 };
  let totalBet = rand(1, funds);
  if (totalBet === 7) {
    totalBet = funds;
    bets.heart = totalBet;
  } else {
    //распределение всех ставок
    let remaining = totalBet;
    do {
      let bet = rand(1, remaining);
      let face = randFace();
      bets[face] = bets[face] + bet;
      remaining = remaining - bet;
    } while (remaining > 0);
  }
  funds = funds - totalBet;
  console.log(
    "tbets: " +
      Object.keys(bets)
        .map(face => "${face}: ${bets[face]} pence")
        .join(", ") +
      " (total: ${totalBet} pence)"
  );

  //Бросок костей
  const hand = [];
  for (let roll = 0; roll < 3; roll++) {
    hand.push(randFace());
  }

  console.log("\thand: ${nand.join(", ")}");

  //Получение выигрыша
  let winnings = 0;
  for (let die = 0; die < hand.length; die++) {
    let face = hand[die];
    if (bets[face] > 0) winnings = winnings + bets[face];
  }
  funds = funds + winnings;
  console.log("\twinnings: ${winnings}");
}

console.log("\tending funs: ${funds}");
```

Comment: Кавычки не те. Для шаблонных строк строго `\``

Comment: Хм, @Darth, ты починиль? Почему не в ответе?

Comment: @vp_arth Проголосовал за закрытие по причине вопрос вызван опечаткой

Comment: @vp_arth там ещев строке 
`  console.log("\thand: ${nand.join(", ")}");` вместо nand должно быть hand

Comment: Это не тот сорт опечаток(имхо), нормальный вопрос. Можно было и ответ написать.

Comment: В любом случае, исправлять проблему вызвавшую вопрос не нужно в самом вопросе.

Comment: c nand как-то глупо вышло, а кавычки сейчас попробую поменять, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ещё кое-какие ошибки были, поправил.

```js
  //возвращает случайное целое число в диапазоне [m, n] (включительно)
function rand(m, n) {
  return m + Math.floor((n - m + 1) * Math.random());
}

//случайно возвращает строку, представляющую одну из шести граней
//Короны и Якоря
function randFace() {
  return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"][rand(0, 5)];
}

let funds = 50; //Начальное условие
let round = 0;

while (funds > 1 && funds < 100) {
  round++;
  console.log(`round ${round}:`);
  console.log(`\tstarting funds: ${funds}p`);

  //Размещение ставок
  let bets = { crown: 0, anchor: 0, heart: 0, spade: 0, club: 0, diamond: 0 };
  let totalBet = rand(1, funds);
  if (totalBet === 7) {
    totalBet = funds;
    bets.heart = totalBet;
  } else {
    //распределение всех ставок
    let remaining = totalBet;
    do {
      let bet = rand(1, remaining);
      let face = randFace();
      bets[face] = bets[face] + bet;
      remaining = remaining - bet;
    } while (remaining > 0);
  }
  funds = funds - totalBet;
  console.log(
    "tbets: " +
      Object.keys(bets)
        .map(face => `${face}: ${bets[face]} pence`)
        .join(", ") +
      ` (total: ${totalBet} pence)`
  );

  //Бросок костей
  const hand = [];
  for (let roll = 0; roll < 3; roll++) {
    hand.push(randFace());
  }

  console.log(`\t nand: ${hand.join(", ")}`);

  //Получение выигрыша
  let winnings = 0;
  for (let die = 0; die < hand.length; die++) {
    let face = hand[die];
    if (bets[face] > 0) winnings = winnings + bets[face];
  }
  funds = funds + winnings;
  console.log(`\twinnings: ${winnings}`);
}

console.log(`\tending funs: ${funds}`);
```